# What is a good and secure way to host SQL and PHP open to the internet?

Tags: server, xampp

I'm using XAMPP locally, but this is only for local use, is there a package like XAMPP that works with public server hosting? Or do I have to install and configure everything manually?

Comment: Q: is there a package like XAMPP that works with public server hosting?  A: Yes - just about any VPS is "like XAMPP".  Q: What is a good and secure way to host SQL and PHP open to the internet?  For starters, lock down every port besides SSH, HTTP and HTTPS.  Then whitelist SSH to "known trusted" IPs. Allow SQL access only within localhost (between your web server and your DB server) - no outside access should be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Azure, it integrates really well with SQL databases and depending on how much storage you need the cost of running is fairly cheap.

Comment: Or AWS.  Or IBM Bluemix or Google Cloud.  Or any number of smaller ISPs, who offer economical [VPS services](https://www.whoishostingthis.com/compare/php/).  There are many, many excellent alternatives, for a wide range of needs.